# Prove that the particular function $^3 +^$, is continuous at  = −1.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Prove that the particular function
$$^3 +^$$
is continuous at $x = −1$. You can assume without proof that the function is differentiable at $x = −1$.
Note: work only with the particular function $x^3 + e^$. A proof involving a general function will NOT attain any mark.

I know a function is continuous if: $$\lim_{x \to -1}f(x) = f(-1)$$
But I am stuck on how to do this question. How do I do this?

Comment: Show that each function is continuous via definition using epsilon-delta and use the fact that the sum of continuous functions are still continuous.

Comment: "Note: works only with the particular function $x^3 + e^x$. A proof involving a general function will NOT attain any mark." Utterly ridiculous. Techniques to solve this apply to a wide variety of functions, specifically any function that is differentiable at $x = -1$.

Comment: How would this be done using epsilon-delta? Thank you

Comment: "and use the fact that the sum of continuous functions are still continuous." I would assume a teacher who says "work only with the particular function" will not accept other methods so as sum of continuous are continuous.  however you can do each with delta eps, and then take two times the minimum delta to combint them.

Answer (score 0):

As the function's differentiable at $\;x=-1\;$ it is *in particular* continuous there, so taking the limit there is just substitution:

$$\lim_{x\to-1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to-1}\left(x^3+e^x\right)=(-1)^3+e^{-1}=e^{-1}-1=f(-1)$$

Comment: "A proof involving a general function will NOT attain any mark."

Comment: .... which in my opinion is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

A function is always continuous wherever it's differentiable. This is because, if $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a$, then,
$$f(x) = f(a) + (x - a)\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} \to f(a) + 0\cdot f'(a) = f(a)$$
as $x \to a$, by algebra of limits.

Answer (score 0):

1) We can prove $g(x) = x^3$ is continuous at $-1$ by noting for any $\epsilon > 0$,

Let $\delta = {\min ( \frac {\epsilon}7,\frac 17)}< 1$ (So $\delta > \delta^2 > \delta^3$)

Then $|x-(-1)|< \delta \implies$

$-\delta < x+1 < \delta$

$-1-\delta < x < -1 + \delta$

$-\delta^3 - 3\delta^2-3\delta - 1 < x^3 < \delta^3 - 3\delta^2 + 3\delta + 1 \implies$

....

$-\epsilon +g(-1) = -7*\frac {\epsilon}7 +(-1) \le$

$-7\delta -1 = -\delta - 3\delta - 3\delta - 1 <-\delta^3 - 3\delta^2-3\delta - 1$

$< x^3 < $

$\delta^3 - 3\delta^2 + 3\delta - 1 < \delta^3 + 3\delta  - 1 <\delta + 3\delta - 1=4\delta -1 < 7\delta -1$

$\le 7\frac {\epsilon}7 +(-1) = \epsilon + g(-1)$

....

$\implies |x^3 - (-1)^3| < \epsilon$.

2) And we can prove $h(x) = e^x$ is continuous at $-1$ by noting for any $\epsilon_1 > 0$,

Let $\epsilon = \min(\epsilon_1, \frac 1e)$

Let $\delta = \ln (\epsilon*e + 1)$

Then $|x -(-1)| < \delta \implies$

$-\delta < x + 1 < \delta$

$-1-\delta < x < -1 + \delta$

$e^{-1-\delta} < e^x < e^{-1+\delta}$

$0 < e^x < \frac 1e*e^{\delta}$

$0< e^x < \frac 1e*e^{\ln (\epsilon*e + 1)}$

So $0< e^x < \frac 1e*(\epsilon*e + 1)$

$0 < e^x < \epsilon + \frac 1e$

$-\frac 1e < e^x-\frac 1e < \epsilon$

$-\epsilon_1 \le -\frac 1e < e^x - e^{-1} <\epsilon \le \epsilon_1$.

$|e^x - e^{-1}|<\epsilon_1$.

3)  Combine the results.

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\epsilon_1 = \min({\frac{\epsilon}2}, \frac 1{7})$ and let $\epsilon 2 = \min(\frac {\epsilon}2, \frac 1e)$.  Let $\epsilon_3 = \min(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$

Let $\delta = \min(\frac {\epsilon_3}7,\ln(\epsilon_3*e + 1))$.

Then $|x -(-1)|< \delta$ implies $|x^3 - (-1)^3|<\epsilon_3 \le \frac {\epsilon}2$

And $|x-(-1)|< \delta$ implies $|e^x - e^{-1}|< \epsilon_3 \le \frac {\epsilon}2$

So $|x-(-1)| < \delta$ implies $|(x^3 + e^x) -((-1)^3 + e^{-1})|\le |x^3 -(-1)^3| + |e^x - e^{-1}| < \frac {\epsilon}2+\frac {\epsilon}2 = \epsilon$.